# how to save uploaded file in another server?

Tags: php, file-upload

I have tow servers for my web site. first, for database and php files. the second, for save useres' uploaded files.

So, if I uploade a file in server-1 xxx.com. how could i save it in server-2 yyy.com??

Comment: Use Curl/Filestreaming to move file1.txt with script1.php to script2.php

Comment: More info please. What is server 2 running? What options do you have to receive a file on server 2? FTP? SSH? PHP? A network share?

Comment: You might want to clearify the scenario. Is this about something like a distributed filesystem?

Answer (score 3):

if you want two servers to be exact clones (contianing same files)  you can run a rsync script after your first uplaod has completed. Its very easy and best of you don't have to specify files.

Lets say you want to transfer all files in directory /files/  to server2 in directory /files/2/ You can run this :

```
rsync /files/ yyy.com:~/files/2/
```

If you ONLY want specific files (extensions) to be synced, you can do this:

```
rsync /files/*.mp3 yyy.com:~/files/2/
```

The above will move ONLY MP3.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply upload one file from server 1 to the server 2 using PHP's FTP functions.

See code example here: http://www.jonasjohn.de/snippets/php/ftp-example.htm

Answer (score 0):

Use shared storage (SAN).  Or SMB shares if on Windows.  Or NFS if on Unix. Or scp (ssh) with public key authentication if on Unix.

Answer (score 0):

An ugly way I used once was to pass via [cURL and FTP commands](http://php.net/manual/fr/book.curl.php)

Of you course, you need to have access to your server-2 FTP...